# Siege doesn't work with big header: [fatal] header is too large

Tags: performance, testing, benchmarking, siege

I am trying to perform load testing of my end-point via connecting to some server via ssh and running siege command there against another server. Unfortunately, when I provide all my cookies in the request:

```
-H $'Cookie:
```

It fails with the following message:

```
 [fatal] header is too large
```

Is there a way siege or other similar tool can work with large headers? Because without sending cookies, my requests don't make any sense and they can't emulate real scenario.

If there is any other tool, It should be something that can be easily run from the command line via ssh without GUI.